# Entity Framework - async select with where multiple conditions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

I'm using ASP.NET Core with Entity Framework.

I have found this working command on Stackoverflow

```
var d = await db.Employee.Where(x => x.FirstName == "Jack").ToListAsync();
```

at the following link :
[Entity Framework - async select with where condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698126/entity-framework-async-select-with-where-condition/69473285#69473285)

Please tell me how can I load the table records into a list based on multiple where conditions.

I want something like that :

```
var d = await db.Employee.Where(x => x.LastName == "Smith" 
                                     and x => x.Country == "UK" 
                                     and x => x.Age == 45 etc)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there

```
var d = await db.Employee.Where(x => x.LastName == "Smith" 
                          && x.Country == "UK"
                           && x.Age == 45)
                          .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It is working !
Thank you very much !

Comment: You are welcome!